# Upgrade Liferay 6.1 to 6.2 GA4, DMS taking much time to upgrade

Tags: liferay

I am trying to upgrade my live portal from LR6.1    to LR6.2 CE-GA4.  Every things is fine except when Liferay upgrades the DMS it takes more than 30 hours,

In 6.1 my DMS is already on 
dl.store.impl=com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.AdvancedFileSystemStore

having size of 29 GB

yes it gives some exceptions that specific file is not found, but upgrades in the end. Pain point is the time it takes to upgrade DMS. As portal is live clients cannot wait so long for up gradation. Kindly suggest the workaround / solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also discussed on liferay forums: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/62218632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do check is there any file missing (while upgrading the log will report) and if there is any then I have written following methods to delete those dangling files first and then start upgrade process.

```
  public void cleanDMS(){
    List <DLFileEntry> fileEntries = null;
    fileEntryId = 0L;
    try {
        fileEntries = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getDLFileEntries(0, DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getDLFileEntriesCount());
        System.out.println("Total file entries in system   "+ fileEntries.size());
        for (DLFileEntry dlFileEntry : fileEntries) {

            getFileAsStream(dlFileEntry.getUserId(), dlFileEntry.getFileEntryId(), dlFileEntry.getVersion());
            //System.out.println("Legal File found ");
        }
        System.out.println("###################################################################################################################");
        System.out.println("total dangling entries found  and deleted are "+ entries.size());
        System.out.println("###################################################################################################################");

    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void getFileAsStream(long userId, long fileEntryIdsss, String version){
    try {
        fileEntryId = fileEntryIdsss;
        DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileAsStream( userId, fileEntryIdsss, version);

    }catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                //DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.deleteDLFileEntry(fileEntryId);
                DLAppLocalServiceUtil.deleteFileEntry(fileEntryId);
            } catch (PortalException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SystemException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("No such file Exception caught for this ");
            entries.add(fileEntryId);
    } catch (PortalException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to identify the root cause problem - you're mentioning that you have 29G of data in the DMS, but it might be unrelated to this: Monitor the upgrade process to see what it's actually doing and where the bottleneck is: Is it a slow NAS that only trickles the data out to Liferay? Is the CPU maxed out when the portal runs its upgrade routines? Can your database handle the updates to the metadata? Are there external resources that are required but can't be fetched during the update time? (E.g. DTD documents, external images that would be embraced in previews)

Further: While it *might* be the DMS, it might also be something completely different.

Another test (in case it *is* the DMS that's running long) that might be worth it is to temporarily migrate the Document Library to another storage, do the upgrade and migrate back. If this runs significantly faster, you're better off, maybe even without fixing the root cause.

Sounds to me like a regular performance tuning job, only this time for a one-shot operation. The algorithm for performance tuning is:

1. identify bottleneck #1 (measure!)
2. fix it

Now bottleneck #2 gets a promotion to the new #1 - rinse&repeat until performance is satisfactory. Never go without the measuring step, as you might start at bottleneck #3, invest a lot of work, only to get 5% more performance instead of the 50% you'd get from #1

Comment: Dear Olaf, checked the CPU utilization it was normal. need to check NAS and database relating issues.

Comment: I will test to migrate the DMS to another storage and try to migrate first

Comment: it was actually 13 DMS files which were missing, wrote a routine to delete these dangling file entries and then upgraded finally